# How do I resize an existing Wubi installation?

Tags: partitioning, wubi, resize

I have Windows 7 as my default OS and 500 GB Hard Disk.

Following is the partition table of my Hard Disk:

[image: partition table]

I have installed Ubuntu with "install inside windows" option.

- `sda1` is the System Reserved space for Windows 7
- `sda2` is the Windows partition (`C:` Drive)
- `sda3` is the Partition inside which I have installed Ubuntu, i.e., it is installed in a folder called *Ubuntu*. I also have some other files in the 200GB partiton
- `sda4` is the common drive where I store all the stuff like Music, Movies, Projects etc.

Now the problem is I have allocated only 25GB as the default installation size in WUBI installer. But I want to increase the size from 25GB to 75 GB or more without losing any files neither in Windows nor Ubuntu.

How do I do that?